# How fix System.FormatException reading data from text file to a listbox

Tags: c#-4.0

My code takes data from form application and displays the result in a listbox and save the data in a file. When next I load the code it should read the data from the file and populate the listbox. I am have a System.FormatException Input string not in correct format.

The code works until I am ready to read the file. I have removed the whitespaces and the dollar sign but the problem is still there. Please any help will be appreciated.

My FileIO class code below

```
public static class FileIO
{
    const string path = "Customers.txt";

    // writes data from the array to the file
    public static void WriteData(List<Customer> customers)
    {
        FileStream fs = null;
        StreamWriter sw = null;
        try
        {
            // open the file for writing; overwrite old content

            fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            // write data
            foreach (Customer item in customers)
                sw.WriteLine(item.DisplayCustomersInfo("|"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error while writing to the file: " +
                ex.Message, ex.GetType().ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sw != null) sw.Close(); // also closes fs
        }
    }

    // reads data from the file, puts in a list, and returns it
    public static List<Customer> ReadData()
    {
        List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

        FileStream fs = null;
        StreamReader sr = null;
        string line; // for reading
        string[] columns; // result from splitting the line
                          // open the file for reading and read number into data
        try
        {
            fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
            sr = new StreamReader(fs);
            while (!sr.EndOfStream) // while there is data in the file
            {
                line = sr.ReadLine(); // read the next line
                line.Trim();
                columns = line.Split(','); // split line into substring from line with comma delimiters

                Customer c = new Customer(Convert.ToInt32(columns[0]), columns[1], Convert.ToChar(columns[2]),
                Convert.ToDecimal(columns[3].Remove(0, 1)));//this is where I think the problem is.

                               customers.Add(c);

            }
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File contains bad format data. Aborting reading");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error while reading the file: "
                + ex.Message, ex.GetType().ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            // close the file if open
            if (sr != null) sr.Close(); //file stream gets closed too
        }
        return customers;
    }
}
```

Below is the text file.

12345|RRRRR|R|$58.05

12345|RRRRR|R|$58.05

12345|RRRRR|R|$58.05

12345|RRRRR|R|$58.05

12345|RRRRR|R|$58.05

12345|CCCCC|C|$60.05

12345|CCCCC|C|$60.05

12345|CCCCC|C|$60.05

12345|CCCCC|C|$60.05

12345|CCCCC|C|$60.05

12345|IIIII|I|$116.09

12345|IIIII|I|$116.09

12345|IIIII|I|$116.09

12345|IIIII|I|$116.09

12345|IIIII|I|$116.09

12345|IIIII|I|$116.09

I have used , and ; as delimiters prior to using |.

I expect to read data from the file and populate the listbox and add more data.

Comment: You split by comma and the file is separated by pipe? Did you check which exact line throws the exception and what exact string is causing it?

Comment: I have used comma for both the split and the file the problem is still there. I just tried it again with the pipe on both. What is throwing the exception is to convert to Int32, ToChar and ToDecimal.

Comment: And what are the exact strings that cause it?

Comment: Put a break point and look at the data it is trying to convert to Int32.  You could also use Int32.TryParse  and when it fails you can check why. AND fix your code as of right now everyone who looks at it will tell you the issue is how you split out the values as your example data shows a pipe but your code is a comma `columns = line.Split(','); `

Comment: I have fixed that as mentioned earlier. I have changed the comma to pipe for both the split and the file delimiter.

Comment: Comment out the try...catch code so that you can find out exactly where it raises the exception and what the data was at that point.

Comment: Thanks all. I found my problem. I have a newline character in my method and this is inserting a blank line on the file.

Comment: @PeterOganwu You could guard against that by checking if `columns.Count = 4` after doing the split.